# Windows Service WebBrowser DocumentCompleted Bug

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, browser

I've been building a Windows Service to create a WebBrowser object to navigate, login, and download a site's HTML. However, I recently discovered this bug which prevents the DocumentCompleted event from firing if the WebBrowser is not visible:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259935

I've got to assume this is because the Windows Service doesn't allow for a GUI and therefore this bug is tripped. What is the best workaround for this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [httpWebRequest](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvcs/thread/4adf8aad-467a-431a-8ae4-9d506db2053c) for this. But its time consuming job while developing. Wont this help?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft does not support using WinInet APIs within the context of a System Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238425). That means webbrowser is not supported too.